# Zoom in while playing a video on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

In my GDK app I start a video like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.google.glass.action.VIDEOPLAYER");
intent.putExtra("video_url", path);
```

The video plays correct.
Is it possible while watching the video to zoom in on the video?

Comment: Hey I have recently been messing around with Glass and video playback. Out of curiosity, you ever figure this out?